Combine RAWs to generate one enhanced RAW (for HDR, noise reduction, etc.)
The expanded question is: what (desktop-based) software can we use to combine multiple RAWs (from the same scene, taken with a traditional camera) to generate a new RAW that combines the best info from these RAWs into an image with more dynamic range and lower noise?
Over the last years, we have seen huge progress in the smartphone department in terms of computational photography, but I am still left wanting by what the camera industry and software companies offer. I would like to continue using dedicated cameras and have been saving bursts of RAWs for dimly-lit scenes and exposure-bracketed RAWs for stunning landscapes, but still cannot process them the way I like.
I am aware that different approaches, each with their advantages and drawbacks, could be taken for this, but I believe that any method (even taking median RGB values) that generates a combined RAW will be better than single RAWs. Yes we can generate HDR JPEGs and noise-reduced JPEGs from image bursts in Lightroom and whatnot, but I would like to keep a single RAW and ditch all the underlying ones instead of deciding to keep one JPEG or even HEIF that represents the way I processed the scene at the moment.
I know that small smartphone sensors gain more from computational photography than large sensors. However, unless you own a full-frame camera, you will find situations where you will want to get more from a scene that you can extract with a single photograph (think low light, or scenes with sunny and shaded spots).
What Apple does in their more recent Pro models is impressive: combining several images to generate a DNG (who would have thought?) "ProRAW". Samsung also started doing this with "Expert RAW". How can we achieve this with RAWs from traditional cameras?
PS: while continuing my search, I found this similar thread.

Raw files have no median RGB values because raw files have no RGB values. They have a single luminance value for each photosite. The CFA is, contrary to all of those cute little drawings all over the internet, NOT "red", "green", and "blue". For most cameras it's violet-blue, slightly yellow green, and yellow-orange. RGB is what our monitors output. There's a lot of overlap between the sensitivity of the green and orange filters, there's some overlap between the violet and green filters, and even some "blue" light gets through the "red" filter.

RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one? and Why can software correct white balance more accurately for RAW files than it can with JPEGs? and RAW to TIFF or PSD 16bit loses color depth and What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?

This question is similar to: Is there any way of achieving cross-application non-destructive RAW editing? (Maybe xmp files?). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You probably won't find many options that write (or re-write) camera-specific raw files directly. But if you convert your raw files to DNG, you can use something like dngmerge to stack or merge your DNGs together. The documentation states,


The output raw file is linearized but not demosaiced unless the source raw files do not need demosaicing (such as Foveon sensors).
Since the script combines raw sensor data together, the resulting image is unaffected by any white balance or post-processing settings saved in the source images.



Thanks scottbb, this one seems to work only on macOS and the dng_stacker repo it is forked from is for Windows. (I am on Linux)

@kdarras It doesn't seem like it would take too much to get the script working on Linux. The actual script is just Bash. It's the dng_validate tool that's platform-specific. It comes from the Adobe DNG SDK. Here's a Gist to build the SDK on Linux. (It's 10 years old, not sure how applicable that is now, though).

Note that DNG are not true raw files for most DNG convertors (including Adobe's). Information is discarded and often white point & black point are "baked in". Sometimes even CT/WB can be "baked in", depending on the DNG convertor. At that point there's not much difference between a DNG and a 16-bit TIFF.
